# Sequelize Change Unique Composites

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using the sequelize syntax to generate a unique composite with two columns in a table like so:

```
sequelize.define('Group', {
    code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: 'GroupCompositeIndex'
    },
    active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        unique: 'GroupCompositeIndex'
    }
});
```

The goal is to have many inactive versions of this group code and change which is active; only one at a time. I will be changing the `active` value to `null` on one record, and to `1` on another. I have never constructed a table to work like this. Will it behave the way I expect by precluding there from ever being 2 groups `active` with the same code, while permitting which group is active to change?